# How to change colors of specific data points in a "series" of a chart?

Tags: c#, charts

[image: screenshot of currently appearing chart]I don't know if can make it clear otherwise, So here is the code:-

```
    Series series2 = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        series2 = chart2.Series.Add(subjectnames[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        series2.Points.Add(attemptper[i]);
        series2.Points.Add(correctper[i]);
    }
```

Now, I just want to display "attemptper" bars in different color than "correctper" bars. By default they are appearing in greyish-blue color. How do I get it done?

The charts appear all in bluish color. I want them to appear in different colors. I think I haven't added the data correctly to the chart for this to achieve?

Comment: It's unclear what are you trying to achieve with this code. You just added 4 series to chart and use only one of them. Maybe it's a good idea to post a screenshot and describe what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest adding an extra series to your chart and changing the color set on that.

Answer (score 12):

You change the color on the series point(index) like this:

```
        Chart1.Series[1].Points[0].Color = Color.Red
```

Getting the chart to repaint might also take some code, depending on what you're doing. For me, I wanted to animate my chart, building the data point (a column) dynamically as the program ran, showing the status of some work I was doing, which required this:

```
        Chart1.Series.ResumeUpdates()
        Chart1.Series[1].Points.Item[0].YValues = Double(1) {MyNewValue, 0}
        Chart1.Series[1].Points[0].Color = Color.Red
        Chart1.DataBind()
        Chart1.Series.Invalidate()
        Chart1.Series.SuspendUpdates()
```